Excel - merging 2 sheets into a third into empty row
I have a master sheet (CMRDETAILS) im taking specific data from certain columns of two other sheets (HistoricalData)(ImportData) and copying it across into the master sheet
Im trying and failing to find the loop to find the last empty cell and enter the data into that row and the empty ones that follow it, the first set of data i move is historical, then copy and paste from Importdata
Is there anyway once knowing the range to set the pasting range to utalise the count?


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filter As String
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim Caption As String
    Dim LR2 As Long
    Dim LR1 As Long
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastCellColRef As Long

Worksheets("ImportData").Cells.Clear

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
filter = "Text files (*.CSV),*.CSV"
    Caption = "Please Select an input file "
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)
    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)
        wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportData").Range("A1")
          wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ImportData")
    Worksheets("ImportData").Range("D:D").EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Worksheets("ImportData").Range("D1").Value = "Month"
            LR1 = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LR2 = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ws.Range("D" & LR2 & ":D" & LR1).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(R[0]C[-1], ""mmm"")"


Sheets("HistoricalData").Range("AE2:AE51").Copy Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("B2:B51")
Sheets("HistoricalData").Range("D2:D51").Copy
Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("A2:A51").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("HistoricalData").Range("Z2:Z51").Copy Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("c2:c51")
 
LastCellColRef = 1  'column number to look in when finding last cell

    Set LastCell = Sheets("CmrDetails").Cells(Rows.Count, LastCellColRef).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    MsgBox LastCell.Address 'just to verify the count is working
     
 
Sheets("ImportData").Range("X2:X350").Copy Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("B52:B350")  'this is the data is want to copy to the empty row
Sheets("ImportData").Range("D2:D51").Copy                                           'this is the data is want to copy to the empty row
Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("A52:A350").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                       'this is the data is want to copy to the empty row
Sheets("ImportData").Range("AX2:AX350").Copy Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("c52:c350")         'this is the data is want to copy to the empty row
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("C2:C350").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NPS")
Set LastCell = Nothing
  MsgBox ("Upload Complete")
   End Sub


no errors I just cant figure out the logic

Import and Consolidate Data
A Quick Fix
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

Dim iws As Worksheet: Set iws = wb.Sheets("ImportData")
Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("CmrDetails")

Dim irg As Range: Set irg = iws.Rows("2:350")
Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) _
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Resize(irg.Rows.Count)
    
iws.Columns("X").Copy Destination:=dws.Columns("B")
dws.Columns("A").Value = iws.Columns("D").Value ' only values
iws.Columns("AX").Copy Destination:=dws.Columns("C")

An Improvement
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ImportCsvData
End Sub

Sub ImportCsvData()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Import CSV Data"
    
    ' Define constants.

    Const SRC_FILE_FILTER As String = "Text files (*.CSV),*.CSV"
    Const SRC_DIALOG_TITLE As String = "Source File Selection"
    
    Const INP_SHEET_NAME As String = "ImportData"
    Const INP_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const INP_INSERT_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const INP_INSERT_COLUMN_FORMULAR1C1 As String = "=TEXT(R[0]C[-1], ""mmm"")"
    
    Const COPY_SHEET_NAME As String = "HistoricalData"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "CmrDetails"
    Const DST_LAST_ROW_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    Const FIRST_ROWS As String = "2:51" ' 50 rows
    Const SECOND_ROWS As String = "52:350" ' 349 rows, maybe "52:351"?
    
    ' Destination
    
    ' Reference the destination workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the Input sheet and clear it.
    Dim iws As Worksheet: Set iws = dwb.Sheets(INP_SHEET_NAME)
    iws.UsedRange.Clear
    
    ' Let the user select a file.
    Dim sFilePath As Variant: sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:=SRC_FILE_FILTER, Title:=SRC_DIALOG_TITLE)
    If sFilePath = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy data from the Source sheet to the Input sheet.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open( _
        Filename:=sFilePath) ' if necessary, try with 'Local:=True'
    Dim ifCell As Range: Set ifCell = iws.Range(INP_FIRST_CELL)
    swb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ifCell
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    ' Destination
        
    ' Insert the specified column and populate it with the header
    ' and formulas from the 2nd to the last row.
    iws.Columns(INP_INSERT_COLUMN).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    With ifCell
        Dim iLR As Long:
        iLR = iws.Cells(iws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        With .EntireRow.Columns(INP_INSERT_COLUMN)
            .Value = "Month" ' write header
            .Offset(1).Resize(iLR - 1) _
                .FormulaR1C1 = INP_INSERT_COLUMN_FORMULAR1C1 ' write formulas
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Reference the Copy and Destination sheets.
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = dwb.Sheets(COPY_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)

    ' Reference the first entire row ranges (the same rows).
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = cws.Rows(FIRST_ROWS)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Rows(FIRST_ROWS)
    
    ' Copy the first ranges (Copy to Destination).
    crg.Columns("AE").Copy Destination:=drg.Columns("B")
    drg.Columns("A").Value = crg.Columns("D").Value ' only values
    crg.Columns("Z").Copy Destination:=drg.Columns("C")
    
    ' Reference the second entire row ranges.
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = iws.Rows(SECOND_ROWS)
    Set drg = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, _
        DST_LAST_ROW_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
        .EntireRow.Resize(irg.Rows.Count)
    
    ' Copy the second ranges (Input to 'first available' row in Destination).
    irg.Columns("X").Copy Destination:=drg.Columns("B")
    drg.Columns("A").Value = irg.Columns("D").Value ' only values
    irg.Columns("AX").Copy Destination:=drg.Columns("C")
    
    ' Hide column 'C' in Destination.
    dws.Columns("C").Hidden = True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Import complete.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub


I've tried the "An Improvement" code, really appreciate the effort in this, it doesn't seem to be copying the data in the "ImportData" sheet and placing it in the "CmrDetails" sheet

If the rest is ok, that could mean there is no data in rows 52 to 350 in columns A, D, and AX of the Input sheet. Also, I ignored that your code copies from D2:D51 to column A almost 5 times considering it as a typo since 2:350 is 349 rows. Please check the former and elaborate on the latter. Try to remove , Local:=True which is necessary in my case and I forgot to remove it.

thank you so the historical data sheets has 44 entries/rows the inputdata has 3 rows but as the year moves so will the amount of data on both tabs, idiotically i though by allowing the scope to include up to 350 rows i was planning against data expansion as the year goes by, now really considering row counts as a function, does the above mean i can just have one row referenced code Const FIRST_ROWS As String = "2:51" '  instead of   Const FIRST_ROWS As String = "2:51" ' 50 rows
Const SECOND_ROWS As String = "52:350"

i matched the two _rows and it works 'FIRST_ROWS As String = "2:51" ' 50 rows Const SECOND_ROWS As String = "2:51"  - thank you for taking the time to help me

Rather than finding the last used cell, we can instead just get the last used row.
LastRow = Sheets("CmrDetails").Cells(Sheets("CmrDetails").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

We can now change the copying of the data from ImportData to be dynamic and the paste into CmrDetails to be in the first open row after the paste from HistoricalData.
Since I don't know what your sheet looks like, all columns copy to the last row of ImportData as stored in LR1. If different columns in ImportData end at different rows, you can calculate each ending row just like you did for LR1 and update the copy code. This might particularly be an issue for you with column D based on your original code.
Sheets("ImportData").Range("X2:X" & LR1).Copy Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("B" & LastRow & ":B" & LastRow + LR1 - 1)
Sheets("ImportData").Range("D2:D" & LR1).Copy
Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & LastRow + LR1 - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("ImportData").Range("AX2:AX" & LR1).Copy Sheets("CmrDetails").Range("C" & LastRow & ":C" & LastRow + LR1 - 1)

